# How to fix "AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'"

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, ubuntu

I have a coding interview tomorrow (my first ever! Super excited/nervous) and am working to bring an old project of mine back to life and updated: a producthunt clone built in Django/Python.

Everything used to run fine with it and now, after git cloning it into a ubuntu virtualbox and bringing things up to date in its virtualenv, I'm stuck with the following error and have come up empty handed after hours of troubleshooting and researching similar issues on stackoverflow. Any help is appreciated.

The error: 'AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF''

Settings and output:

settings.py

```
"""
Django settings for producthunt project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.10.5.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/
"""
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = '@(b=ndac@9k%w#y7(h5p!^a!)6y_p2&oln@lsz6x61=wyusg4('

import os
import django
django.setup()

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ROOT_URLCONF = 'producthunt.urls'

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'compressor',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django_comments',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'bootstrap4',
    'producthunt',
    'links',
    'registration',
]

# Login/out settings - plus import above
from django.urls import reverse

LOGIN_URL=reverse('login')
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = reverse('home')

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]


TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'producthunt.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}

SITE_ID = 1

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True

COMPRESS_ENABLED = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATIC_ROOT = 'static'
MEDIA_ROOT = 'media'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'compressor.finders.CompressorFinder',
)

COMPRESS_PRECOMPILERS = (
    ('text/x-scss', 'django_libsass.SassCompiler'),
)
```

urls.py:

```
"""producthunt URL Configuration

The `urlpatterns` list routes URLs to views. For more information please see:
    https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/http/urls/
Examples:
Function views
    1. Add an import:  from my_app import views
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', views.home, name='home')
Class-based views
    1. Add an import:  from other_app.views import Home
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^$', Home.as_view(), name='home')
Including another URLconf
    1. Import the include() function: from django.conf.urls import url, include
    2. Add a URL to urlpatterns:  url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls'))
"""
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views
from links.views import LinkListView
from links.views import UserProfileDetailView
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required as auth # Keep non-users out
from links.views import UserProfileEditView
from links.views import LinkCreateView, LinkDetailView
from links.views import LinkEditView
from links.views import LinkDeleteView

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', LinkListView.as_view(), name='home'),
    url(r'^login/$', auth_views.login, name='login'),
    url(r'^logout/$', auth_views.logout, name='logout'),
    url(r'^accounts/', include('registration.backends.simple.urls')),
    url(r'^users/(?P<slug>\w+)/$', UserProfileDetailView.as_view(),name='profile'),
    url(r'^edit_profile/$', auth(UserProfileEditView.as_view()), name='edit_profile'),
    url(r'^link/submit/$', auth(LinkCreateView.as_view()), name='link_submit'),
    url(r'^link/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', LinkDetailView.as_view(), name='link_detail'),
    url(r'^link/edit/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', auth(LinkEditView.as_view()), name='link_edit'),
    url(r'^link/delete/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', auth(LinkDeleteView.as_view()), name='link_delete'),
    url(r'^comments/', include('django_comments.urls')),
]
```

Full terminal output:

```
(producthunt) ubuntu@ubuntu-VirtualBox:~/Documents/Github/producthunt$ python manage.py runserver
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 325, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 79, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 66, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 157, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/ubuntu/Documents/Github/producthunt/producthunt/settings.py", line 53, in <module>
    LOGIN_URL=reverse('login')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/base.py", line 30, in reverse
    resolver = get_resolver(urlconf)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 68, in get_resolver
    urlconf = settings.ROOT_URLCONF
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 80, in __getattr__
    val = getattr(self._wrapped, name)
AttributeError: 'Settings' object has no attribute 'ROOT_URLCONF'
```

Comment: Have you tried to add a variable ROOT_URLCONF pointing to your urls file in you settings file, just before the line 53?

Comment: @NicoT As in move it (ie. ROOT_URLCONF='producthunt.urls')  from line 28 to line 52? Just tried it but no luck.

Comment: Are you sure `import django` belongs in settings.py?  Did you add that yourself, or did you copy it from some example code?

Comment: @JohnGordon That was from some example code where a guy was bug testing something similar. Without import django and django.set() on lines 16 and 17 I get the error: 'django.core.exceptions.AppRegistryNotReady: Apps aren't loaded yet.'

I may or may not need it in there. It doesn't appear in basic installs of Django from what I've seen, but has just been another test I've tried.

Comment: I'm used to those two lines being in the `manage.py` script, not in `settings.py`.

Comment: can you add the code in your manage.py and wsgi.py?
Also are you sure all your paths in your INSTALLED_APPS are correct?

Comment: @JohnGordon Just tried moving them over there and I get an error about Django requested setting logging)config but the settings are not configured. That I must either defined the environment variable django_settings_module or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.

Comment: @NicoT Happy to try. Which code specifically? The current wsgi.py code looks as such:

import os

from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "producthunt.settings")

application = get_wsgi_application()

EDIT:
Path should be fine for installed_apps but I might be wrong. Here a screenshot of the file/folder structure: https://imgur.com/a/5miTrto

Comment: SOLVED. There were a few things wrong. Since upgrading the django install from like 1.10 to 2.2, there were a lot of changes. Including URL referencing (ie. django.conf.urls vs django.urls) and having to re-run requirements.txt to make sure everything was installed and updated correctly.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED. There were a few things wrong. Since upgrading the django install from like 1.10 to 2.2, there were a lot of changes. Including URL referencing (ie. django.conf.urls vs django.urls) and having to re-run requirements.txt to make sure everything was installed and updated correctly.